# Why does addColumn() fail immediately after crating a Tabulator object, yet works later on?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

There appears to be a race condition in the creation of my Tabulator object, such that I cannot perform addColumn() immediately afterwards.

In the beginning of my code, I create a Tabulator object with some columns.  Immediately afterwards, I add 52 nearly identical columns (except for the name) using a for loop.  I've put in a .then and a .error on the allColumn() promise, and the error portion gets executed. So, I'm getting the error (52 times):

```
"there was a problem" 1 "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')"
"there was a problem" 2 "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')"
"there was a problem" 3 "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')"
...
"there was a problem" 52 "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')"
```

That is telling me that the HTML isn't there yet. However, I know the div is there, and the Tabulator does get created with the columns I have in the constructor.

I tried putting the addColumn() code in a separate function, then running it from the console window.  When I do that, it works!  Again, this is telling me the addColumn() method is being called before the Tabulator object is completely created.  See my code below:

```
AJS.toInit(function () {
    gToday = new Date();
    gToday.setMinutes(gToday.getMinutes() - gToday.getTimezoneOffset());

    // Prepare Tabulator tables
    dataTable = new Tabulator("#HoursTabulatorDiv", {
            autoColumns: false,
            //layout: "fitColumns",
            //layoutColumnsOnNewData: true, // Auto-adjust column widths when data changes
            height: 500,
            columns: [
                {  
                   title:"Selected",
                   field:"Selected",
                   hozAlign:"center",
                   formatter:"tickCross",
                   width:90,
                   frozen:true,
                   formatterParams:{
                       allowEmpty:false,
                       allowTruthy:false,
                   },
                   cellClick: function(e, cell) {
                   }
               },

               {
                   title:"id",
                   field:"id",
                   frozen:true,
                   visible: true
               },
                {
                    title: "Name",
                    field: "Name",
                    minWidth: 175,
                    editable:false,
                    editor: "input",
                   frozen:true,
                    resizable:true
                },

               {
                    title: "Dept",
                    field: "Dept",
                    editable:true,
                    editor: "list",
                    editorParams:{
                        // Departments
                        values:["10A", "10B", "13A", "17C", "20B", "21A","NA"],
                    },
                    minWidth: 50,
                   frozen:true,
                    resizable:true
                }

            ]
        });


  run();


});

function run()
{

     dataTable.addColumn({title:"test", field:"test"});


    for (let i=1; i<=MAXWEEKS; i++)
    {
        dataTable.addColumn({
                    title:"Week "+i.toString()+" Hours",
                    field:"week"+i.toString()+"hours",
                    minWidth: 50,
                    resizable:true,
                    editable: true,
                    editor: "number",
                    visible: true
                }).then(function(column){
       //column - the component for the newly created column

       //run code after column has been added
        console.log("the column was added", i);
    }).catch(function(error){
    //handle error adding column
       console.log("there was a problem", i, error.message);
    });


        console.log("adding column to data table", i);
    }
 

}
```

The above code results in the original columns being displayed: [image]

However, when I run the "run();" function later, I get what I was expecting, the original columns plus the added columns being displayed: [image]

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?  I've added columns in another application before, without any problems.

Update: I forced a "sleep", and it works.  I shouldn't have to do this though.:

```
...
demo().then(function(){

  run();

    });
```

---

Then later:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(`Waiting ${i} seconds...`);
        await sleep(i * 1000);
    }
    console.log('Done');
}
```

Comment: What is `AJS.toInit`?

Comment: AJS.toInit is specific to Confluence; it takes the place of:  $(document).ready(function(){ ...

Comment: Try `dataTable.on("tableBuilt", run);` to make sure `run()` is called after table has finished being rendered.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I tried that, and the table was displayed, but missing all of the column headers.  That's very strange.  Forcing it to sleep for 1 second seems to work the most consistently, even though it's kludgy.